# Scrolling to bottom of UITextView does not display last lines

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView for data entry with a fixed height (constrained by the space available) that can show 4 lines of data.

As data is entered it wraps within the textview.  Scrolling is enabled so that when the rows of data exceed the vertical space available the user can scroll up or down to the top or bottom.

The problem is that when there are more than 4 rows, scrolling to the bottom just bounces back up to show the top 4 rows when released.

If I disable `Bounce on Scroll` I can't see any of the lines below the 4th.

If there are 8 lines, I can not scroll far enough to see the last line.

How get it to scroll to the bottom and stop there with the bottom line displayed?

Comment: You must have some code executing based on user input... that's certainly not the "default" behavior.

Comment: I see what happened.  I added some buttons below the textView and did not reduce the size of the textView.  As a result, the bottom of the textview is hidden by the buttons.  Presumably, if those buttons were invisible, I would be able to see the rest of the textView and that it is indeed scrolling to the bottom.  The top rows are scrolling off the top as expected.